# verify canonically conjugate variables by way of Poisson brackets

Tags: hamiltonian-formalism, poisson-brackets, canonical-conjugation

How do I verify using Poisson brackets that a set of variables are canonically conjugate? It's for a homework problem but I'm interested in a general approach/reference if possible. We are using Goldstein's Classical Mechanics but I have been unable to locate any passages about this in the book so I turn to you. :-)

Best regards,

Comment: "Hidden" near the end of the section on Poisson brackets in that book is a calculation of the Poisson bracket between two conjugate variables. The result is 1. So, compute the POisson bracket, and if it's equal to 1, then the variables are canonical conjugates.

Comment: Thank you so much :)